# Rstudio error: ERROR session hadabend; LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::Error {anonymous}

Tags: r, docker, session, rstudio, crash-reports

I am having a rstudio setup in a docker container and was trying to use a function from a package to plot pca and it was working fine, but later it stopped working with the below error:

```r
31 May 2021 07:12:50 [rsession-rstudio] ERROR session hadabend;
LOGGED FROM: rstudio::core::Error {anonymous}::rInit(const
rstudio::r::session::RInitInfo&) src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:680
```

This error message is not giving any clue about where it crashes actually. Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: I have been facing the same recently with R Studio server having R 4.0.3. I loaded my session, workspace with all the libraries and images. Seemed to work fine but then, when I tried to run some new snippets of functions it crashed.